# my input program, in double linked list terminates with error code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

this is my function to inpute data in a double linked list

```
void input(int element){
struct node *p=head,*q=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(p==NULL){
    head=q;
    q->data=element;
    q->prev=NULL;
    q->next=NULL;
}
else{
    while(p->next!=NULL){
        p=p->next;
    }
    p->next=q;
    q->prev=p;
    q->next=NULL;
    q->data=element;
}}
```

this is my function to display data in double linked list

```
void display(){
struct node *p=head;
while(p!=NULL){
    p=p->next;
    printf("%d   ",p->data);
}
printf("\n");}
```

if i input one or more data to my double linkd list and try to display my linked list ,the programs terminate with error code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

if i input 1,2,3,4 to my linked list
output is:

2   3   4
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

here is the complete code of my program:

```
struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
}*head=NULL;
void display(){
struct node *p=head;
while(p!=NULL){
    p=p->next;
    printf("%d   ",p->data);
}
printf("\n");
}
void input(int element){
struct node *p=head,*q=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(p==NULL){
    head=q;
    q->data=element;
    q->prev=NULL;
    q->next=NULL;
}
else{
    while(p->next!=NULL){
        p=p->next;
    }
    p->next=q;
    q->prev=p;
    q->next=NULL;
    q->data=element;
}
}
int main() {
int x;
while(1){
    printf("Press   1.INSERT   4.DISPLAY ALL ELEMENTS   5.QUIT   \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==1){
        int element;
        printf("\n write your element");
        scanf("%d",&element);
        input(element);
    }

    else if(x==4){
        display();
    }
    else if (x==5){
        return 0;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you're at the last item in the list (which means `p!=NULL`) and you then assign `p=p->next`? What is the `printf` going to print at that point? What is `p->next` when `p` is the last item in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the function display due to the invalid order of two statements.

Instead of

```
void display(){
struct node *p=head;
while(p!=NULL){
    p=p->next;
    printf("%d   ",p->data);
}
printf("\n");}
```

It should look at least like

```
void display(){
struct node *p=head;
while(p!=NULL){
    printf("%d   ",p->data);
    p=p->next;
}
printf("\n");}
```